# How can I select all unread messages on the new version of Yahoo Mail?

Tags: yahoo-mail, delete

A friend tells me on the old Yahoo Mail she used to use an option to select all unread mail in order to delete them all.

But in the new Yahoo Mail interface this option doesn't seem to exist. But is it maybe hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the steps you can follow to delete unread messages but it's not a clean way but you've only this option to do so :

1. Change your view to "**Sort by Unread**". View is on the same row as the Delete button.
2. Here you have two options, you can either, click on the individual unread message or you can click on the select all check box and deselect all the read messages. Which ever that requires less clicking. Either way, you want to have only the unread messages selected.

and select "**Delete**"

Comment: Once they're ordered this way you can also click on the select box of the first one you want to get rid of, hold shift, then click on the select box of the last one, then hit "delete".

Comment: Well this does seem to be the only way so you get the cookie (-:

Answer (score 4):

Just type `is:unread` in the search bar and click on *Search mail*. Then if you want to delete them all at once, click on *Select all* and *Delete*.

Comment: Will "select all" select all the ones currently visible, or all the ones that are unread?

Answer (score 1):

I delete my messages as follows:  Select page you want to delete (in my case I view 200 messages per page), select sort by date, all of the messages on that page will be selected, then select delete, all messages on that page will be deleted.  Repeat process for each page you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

To delete items showing in INBOX as unread

Using Yahoo 7  -  If you right click on INBOX  a drop down box will appear with

Mark as Read - Left click on this box and it's done.

They are deleted from your 'unread'  without being seen by you.  If you want to read them don't do this because you have no way of identifying which ones they were.  They are now listed as 'read.'

Answer (score 0):

Just click purple box next to From header.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a picture, so that people see what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Use Advanced Filter, then pick out all messages in inbox with a common keyword, then "Select All" or Ctrl+A, delete, you can do more than 100k messages at once but it's slow.

Answer (score 0):

Type **is:unread** in search box. Select **Mark as Read** in drop-down menu labeled **More**

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delete the unread items within a specific folder then you can enter the command

```
in:Foldername is:unread
```

click on the *Search* button. Select all by clicking the checkbox in the header and click *Delete*. This will delete all unread messages in the folder.

If you want to delete all the mails, regardless whether they are read/unread, just type `in:Foldername`, search and delete.

Answer (score 0):

In the search box type: `is:unread` then left-click the box above the emails and select all
then hit delete icon.

It will delete hundreds at a time to the trash.

Comment: How is this any different from @Sree's already-upboted answer?